# Giving properties to Zoomify layers in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using `OpenLayers.Layer.Zoomify` to show large image files and this works like a charm. The only thing is that I would like to add some options to that layer ( opacity and transitionEffect) but it doesn't seem to work. Code:

```
var zoomify = new OpenLayers.Layer.Zoomify( "Zoomify",
  zoomify_url, 
  new OpenLayers.Size( zoomify_width, zoomify_height ),
  { opacity: 0.5, transitionEffect: 'resize'}
);
```

Isn't this the right way of doing it? Or is it not possible to add these properties to Zoomify layers? Nothing happens to my zoomify layer.

Comment: Really neat idea, I'd like to understand how to accomplish this as well!

Answer (score 1):

**Layer Opacity control**

[image]

```
var map = null;
    var shade = null;
    var maxOpacity = 0.9;
    var minOpacity = 0.1;
    function changeOpacity(byOpacity) {
        var newOpacity = (parseFloat(OpenLayers.Util.getElement('opacity').value) + byOpacity).toFixed(1);
        newOpacity = Math.min(maxOpacity,
                              Math.max(minOpacity, newOpacity));
        OpenLayers.Util.getElement('opacity').value = newOpacity;
        shade.setOpacity(newOpacity);
    }
```

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/layer-opacity.html

Comment: Interesting! But the most important (for me) remains: `transitionEffect`

Comment: Oskar like this? http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/transition.html

Comment: Yes, exactly, but working with Zoomify layers.